# Overlapping accesses to "result", but modification requires exclusive access; consider copying to a local variable in xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift

```
open static func PBKDF2(_ password: String, salt: Data,
                        prf: PRFAlg, rounds: UInt32) throws -> Data {
    var result = Data(count:prf.cc.digestLength)
    let passwData = password.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let status = result.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (passwDataBytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) -> CCCryptorStatus in
        return CCKeyDerivationPBKDF!(
            PBKDFAlgorithm.pbkdf2.rawValue,
            (passwData as NSData).bytes, 
            passwData.count,
            (salt as NSData).bytes, 
            salt.count,
            prf.rawValue,
            rounds,
            passwDataBytes,
            result.count)
     }

     guard status == noErr else { throw CCError(status) }

     return result
}
```

`result.withUnsafeMutableBytes` is giving an error in Xcode 10, In Xcode 9 it is a warning.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That is a consequence of [SE-0176 Enforce Exclusive Access to Memory](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0176-enforce-exclusive-access-to-memory.md), which was implemented in Swift 4
and is more strict in Swift 4.2.

The solution is to assign the count to a separate variable:

```
let count = result.count
let status = result.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
    (passwDataBytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) -> CCCryptorStatus in
        return CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(..., count)
}
```

or to capture the count in a capture list:

```
let status = result.withUnsafeMutableBytes { [ count = result.count ]
    (passwDataBytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) -> CCCryptorStatus in
        return CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(..., count)
}
```

See also [Overlapping access warning in withUnsafeMutableBytes](https://forums.swift.org/t/overlapping-access-warning-in-withunsafemutablebytes/12171) in the Swift forum

> [**hamishknight**](https://forums.swift.org/t/overlapping-access-warning-in-withunsafemutablebytes/12171/4):
>
> withUnsafeMutableBytes(_:) is a mutating method on Data, therefore it requires write access to data for the duration of the call. By accessing data.count in the closure, you’re starting a new read on data which conflicts with the current write access.
>
> [**Joe_Groff**](https://forums.swift.org/t/overlapping-access-warning-in-withunsafemutablebytes/12171/6):
>
> You could also capture a copy of data or its count in the closure’s capture list: ...
>
> The capture list gets evaluated and the results captured by value when the closure is formed, before the exclusive access begins, avoiding the overlapping access.

and [this comment](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/15915#issuecomment-381164546) in
the corresponding pull request:

> Here an appropriate fix is to copy the count of buffer outside of the closure and pass that to inet_ntop() instead.

Update for **Swift 5:**

```
let status = result.withUnsafeMutableBytes { [ count = result.count ]
    (bufferPointer) -> CCCryptorStatus in
    let passwDataBytes = bufferPointer.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self).baseAddress
    return CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(..., passwDataBytes, count)
}
```

Comment: When I try the `capture list` the error is `Use of unresolved identifier _count_`

Comment: @javadba: `_count_` with the underscores? I wonder where that comes from.

Comment: That was intended as formatting (for the SOF comment) only - should be `count` .  I was not able to use the `capture list` approach: it gave syntax errors . I ended up using a local copy before the `withUnsfafeMutableBytes` in place of `count`

Comment: @javadba: If you have a  GitHub Gist with some self-contained code demonstrating the problem then I can take a look on it.